# Where is the mistake in my dp approach here? https://www.spoj.com/problems/AE00/

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem:

> Byteman has a collection of N squares with side 1. How many different
>   rectangles can he form using these squares?
>
> Two rectangles are considered different if none of them can be rotated
>   and moved to obtain the second one. During rectangle construction,
>   Byteman can neither deform the squares nor put any squares upon any
>   other ones.
>
> Input The first and only line of the standard input contains one
>   integer N (1 <= N <= 10000).
>
> Output The first and only line of the standard output should contain a
>   single integer equal to the number of different rectangles that
>   Byteman can form using his squares.
>
> Example For the input data: 6
>
> the correct result is: 8

My Solution:

```
public class Rectangles {
    public void solve(int testNumber, Reader in, OutputWriter out) {
        try {
            while(true) {
                int N = in.ni();
                out.printLine(result(N));
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) { }
    }

    private long result(int n) {
        long[] res = new long[n+2];
        res[0] = 0;
        res[1] = 1;
        res[2] = 2;
        for(int i=3;i<=n;i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                res[i] = 3 + res[i-2];
            } else {
                res[i] = 1 + res[i-1];
            }
        }
        return res[n];
    }
}
```

My DP Approach:

```
For 0 squares: Result is 0
For 1 square: Result is 1: f(1) = 1
For 2 squares: Result is 2 : f(2) = 2
Now for f(3) = f(2) + 1 more square
With 1 more square we can only place it horizontally and hence 
f(3) = f(2)+1, generalizing, when n is ODD : f(n) = f(n-1) + 1
when n is EVEN: we use two squares which can make up to 3 rectangles, two horizontally([SQ] & [SQ][SQ]) plus one on top of the other, so total 3 possibilities, and hence f(n) when n is EVEN: f(n) = f(n-2) + 3.
```

Comment: Please state your output (I guess it's not 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `N` all possible different rectangles are:

```
  1x1 1x2 1x3 1x4 ... 1x[N/1]
      2x2 2x3 2x4 ... 2x[N/2] // 2x1 is equals to 1x2 
          3x3 3x4 ... 3x[N/3] // 3x1 and 3x2 are equal to 1x3 and 2x3
                  ... 
                      Mx[N/M]
```

Where `[...]` means *integer part* (`floor`) or, in other words, `[N/M]` is *integer division*. Since `N` is not very large, we can just loop

**C# Code:**

```
private static int Solution(int value) {
  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
    int upTo = value / i;

    if (i > upTo)
      return result;

    result += (upTo - i + 1);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  int[] tests = new int[] {
    0,
    1,
    6,
    9,
    10000,
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,5} -> {Solution(test),5}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
    0 ->     0
    1 ->     1
    6 ->     8
    9 ->    13
10000 -> 46884
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all rectangles are obtained from adding one square to an existing rectangle.

For example, if N = 9, one of the rectangles is 3x3. Your DP approach will not find it. Or, in other words, f(9) > f(8) + 1.

Comment: Thank you. Just thought of this case little back. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to consider how many rectangles with the smaller(!) side being length *x* can exist.  Then loop through all possible values for *x* and sum them up.  *Pseudo-code:*

```
result = 0
for x in 1 .. floor(sqrt(n)):
  result += number_of_rectangles_with_smaller_side(x)
```

And I think `number_of_rectangles_with_smaller_side(x)` is `floor(n / x) - x + 1` but you should double check that ;-)